# Convert string to byte[] do an operation and back to byte[]

Tags: java, vb.net, byte

I'm converting an old VB.net project to Java (I barely know any VB).

```
Dim asciis As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name)
For i As Int32 = 0 To asciis.Length - 1
  asciis(i) = CByte(asciis(i) + 1)
Next
Dim encryptedName As String = StrReverse(Uri.EscapeDataString(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(asciis, 0, asciis.Count())))
```

I converted it to:

```
byte[] asciis = name.getBytes();
for (int i =0; i<asciis.length-1;i++){
   asciis[i] = (byte)(asciis[i]+1);
}
String encryptedName = StringUtils.reverse(asciis.toString()).substring(0,asciis.length);
```

I converted the `name` `29384` and the .Net gives `594A3%3` while my Java code gives `d9354`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try changing `length-1` to `length`.

Comment: ASCII.GetBytes() replaces every character outside the [C0 Controls and Basic Latin](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) block with '?'.  Is that a behavior you want to replicate?

Comment: it opens an url with the 'encrypted' number so I want to duplicate it to see what website it opens :)

Comment: so No that's not what the VB.net code seems to do.

Comment: Fundamentally, once you've performed almost any operation on the binary data, it shouldn't be treated as if it were still encoded text.

Comment: So the solution I got is a bad practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright as @Nyamiou said I had to give the charset to the String and encode it with an URLEncoder.

```
byte[] asciis = number.getBytes(Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
for (int i =0; i<asciis.length;i++){
   asciis[i] = (byte)(asciis[i]+1);
}
String asciiString = new String(asciis, Charset.forName("US-ASCII"));
String encryptedNumber= StringUtils.reverse(URLEncoder.encode(asciiString, "US-ASCII"));
```

Answer (score 1):

This `asciis.toString()` is not correct (it will give you the adress of the array instead), you need to do `new String(asciis, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` to create the String from the array of bytes. And you need to apply `URLEncoder.encode(newString, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())` to apply the same URI encoding that is done in your VB code. Also you need to do `name.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` instead of just `name.getBytes()`, because else you'll use the default charset of the operating system it's running on, and it might not be ASCII compatible.

Comment: it's a Java 6 project and `import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets` is from jdk 1.7 so can't use that.

Comment: Use Charset.forName("UTF-8") instead, but stop using Java 6, it way too old and not supported anymore.

Comment: don't have much of a choice but we're converting, by next year all code should be java 8.